# Is this way of abstracting template Matrix class data type good?

Tags: c++, oop

I recently had to write my own matrix multiplication library. Initially, I wrote it as a template class then I realized that most classes use the matrix class without caring about the datatype used by Matrix class because they just perform a certain transformation and to the matrix without checking the result. So they really ought to not be aware of  the datatypes. I was thinking of making a matrix class with a void pointer to the data.

```
    class Mat
    {
    private:
        void *data;
        int dtype; // data type used by matrix
        int cols, rows;

        template<class type>
        Mat add(const Mat& a, type unused); // notice unused parameters

    public:
        Mat(int dtype);
        ~Mat();
        Mat operator+(const Mat& a);
        template<class type>
        type* getdata(); // this only function  that exposes the 
        //datatype to the user since they want to read the elements
    };
```

I need a the addition function to be a template since its accelerating computations using SSE intrinsics and I have abstracted the intrinsics using template classes. So I thought  of adding an unused parameter to the template add so that the compiler would be able to distinguish between the different templates.

```
Mat Mat::operator+(const Mat& a)
{
    Mat result;

    switch(dtype)
    {
        case 0: // int
            result = this->add<int>(a, 0);
            break;
        case 1: // float
            result = this->add<float>(a, 0);
            break;
    };

    return result;
}
```

Is this a bad idea ? if not any way to get rid of the unused parameter in the add method ?

Another Idea I had was to Make IntMatrix, Float Matrix classes inherit from Mat class just to have it call the add function with the template type to avoid having the case switch in  the operator overload of the addition. Is this also a bad design ?

**clarification**

I want to be able to have 2 vectors:

```
vector<Transform*> transformVector; // list of classes doing operation on matrix
vector<Mat*> results; // intermediate results vector

results.push_back(input_mat)
for(int i = 0; i < transformVector.size(); ++i){
    results.push_back(transformVector[i]->transform(results[i]));
// transform here might have to return a result of type float
// even though the input was of type int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to make the `Mat` class templated and let the compiler create the necessary add functions.

With the current implementation, you'd have to add a new switch case for each new type, and be careful to properly cast the `void*` to the right type. When you use templates, the compiler will helps you out by checking your types.

You could even create a template which lets you add a `Mat<int>` to a `Mat<float>` (or two other matrices of different types).

```
template <typename T, size_t Col, size_t Row>
Mat {
    std::array<T, Col * Row> data; // or other data structure
    // ...
    template <typename OtherT>
    add(const Mat<OtherT, Col, Row>& other);
};
```

Comment: Problem I have is that the classes performing the transformations on the matrices end up being templates and not use the same datatype. Thats why o wanted to change it since i wanted all classes to he stored in one vector without dynamic casting, also i wanted to store the matrices regardless of their type in a map

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know the type of the matrices am going to use until i read some file during run-time containing the matrix values thus i wanted to delay taking decision how to perform the operations  util I know exactly what type  of data I will use to perform the computation

Comment: Your implementation is still using dynamic casts and polymorphism - you're just re-implementing them yourself using `void*` casts and `switch` statements.

Comment: I realize this but i need to be able to do the following: vector<Transform*> transformVector; vector<Mat*> results

Answer (score 1):

One hard point here is `type * getData()`.
Here again, either you return a plain `void *` and require the caller to do an explicit cast on it, or you have to use a templated function.

Long story made short, you have changed a templated class (where the overload are resolved at compile time) for a bunch of template methods and a bit of switches to resolve some of the functions at run time.

You say *most classes use the matrix class without caring about the datatype*. That is exactly what templates are made for: a bunch of storage and processing that is independant of the underlying type (well templates can do a little more, but were initialy created for that)

`void *` is always a safe pointer and is a great choice for C compatible APIs. But unless you have performance problems (templates can use too much memory on tiny systems because they declare a different class for each implementation (*)), and can prove that a `void *` is better for a specific use case, you should stick to the common rules. Write simple and easy to read code, and only optimize when you have found a bottleneck.

After your edit, I can see that you want to store matrixes of different underlying types in a single container. I can imagine polymorphism if all matrixes can derive from a common non templated type but I would not be surprised if you suddenly fall in the *`type * getData()`* problem later: you static cast a void pointer, so the compiler has no way to prevent you to do a bad cast. An other possibility would be `std::variant` on matrixes (if C++17) or `boost::variant` or any other *variant* or *any* alternative. Some of them implement tricks for preventing bad casts at run time.

Hard to know which way is best without experimenting over the real problem...

---

Some other languages like Java have not *templates* (a different class for each and every implementation) but *generics* (a common class that acts on *objects*). The pros is only one class so the question about the correct template not being available at link time has vanished, the cons is that it requires some tricks to make the actual type available at run time.

Comment: "most classes use the matrix class without caring about the datatype" What I mean't with this, is that the class performing the transformation  should not be aware of the type as in it shouldn't have to say Mat<int> or mat<float>. With my current implementation, the convolution class I have is also a template class since it has member variable called kernel. So it ended up having to make my transformation classes templates just to store the matrices that perform the transformation with the correct type.

Comment: So now my tansformation class is declared template<class type> convolution so that its inner variable kernel is Mat<type> convolution__kernel.

Comment: Only hints, since I am not sure to clearly understand what is the *transformation class*. The common patterns it C++ to allow to do the same operation on objects of different types are polymorphism and templates. In C++17 the `any` and `variant` datatype (from boost) can also help.

Comment: Think of transformation class as something that takes a matrix and does some computation it. It could be just adding some scalar to a matrix, it could be multiplying it by another matrix which is a member variable in the class or performing convolution for instance. The Transformation class it self doesn't implement the code for performing the action of addition, multiplication. it just specifies the series of operations to perform on an Input matrix

Comment: Id consider this an example of a transformation class https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution

Comment: I have added some information under bold title clarification to make this clear

Comment: @KarimMohamedHasebou: ... and I have edited my answer

Comment: why do you consider the getData() function a bad idea ? Is it because the user of the class now has to specify the datatype to use manually ?

Comment: @KarimMohamedHasebou I didn't pay attention to the `template <class type>` above, because I am used to uppercase or capitalized names for template classes. Post edited